# Do Wall-E and Big Hero 6 take place in the same city?

Tags: reference, wall-e, big-hero-6

The cities of [Wall-E](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0910970/) (2008) and [Big Hero 6](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2245084/) (2014) hold some similarities (mainly because of their San Francisco-esque style): close architecture, tall buildings, by a bay...

Hiro is a 14-year old robot designer from an unknown time, likely beginning-mid XXI century, around 50-100 years before the events that take place in Wall-E. And during the movie, something that looks like [EVE](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0089609/)'s head can be seen on Hiro's desk:

[image: Screenshot of Big Hero 6]

Although as [Paulie_D says in the chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40681730#40681730), this could be just another easter egg in a movie full of them.

Is there any official confirmation from the makers that the cities are the same? Or if they both happen in the same universe?

I am not looking for the city in which San Fransokyo/Wall-E are based on in real life. What I want to know is if, within Disney universe, Wall-E's city is San Fransokyo.

Comment: The city in Wall-E consists of towering trash heaps. The two movies were animated by different studios. BH6 is based on a pre-existing comic. And we have no indication when Wall-E takes place relative to the present. I don't see the reason for assuming they take place in the same city.

Comment: While there doesn't seem to be any explicit indication either way (at least that I've been able to find so far), the intro scene for WALL-E (where they're zooming in from above the Earth) makes it appear that he is working in the New England area of the United States.  If we assume that San Fransokyo is located on the west coast as it's name seems to imply, this would preclude the two cities from being the same.

Answer (score -1):

"Big Hero 6" takes place in the imaginary city of ["San Fransokyo"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Hero_6_(film)). One would assume from the name that it shares similarities to San Francisco and Tokyo.

It's never said in "Wall-E" what city he's cleaning up. However, [Wikipedia points out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WALL-E) that:

> Pixar studied Chernobyl and the city of Sofia to create the ruined world; art director Anthony Christov was from Bulgaria and recalled Sofia used to have problems storing its garbage.

Pixar is located near San Francisco, and during production even [borrowed a bomb detecting robot from the San Francisco Police Department](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WALL-E#Animation). So it would seem that San Francisco was likely also an influence on them.

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question (sorry if I didn't make it clear). I am not looking for the city in which San Fransokyo/Wall-E are based on in real life. What I want to know is if, within Disney universe, Wall-E's city is San Fransokyo.

Answer (score -1):

At the start of *WALL•E* it zooms into the Eastern part of the world. So maybe Kentucky, Tennessee, or North Carolina.

Since *Big Hero 6* is based off San Fransisco, which is in California, the answer would be no.